(Springboot Gradle with Log4j2, Executable Jar) Could not find or load main class
I encountered the following error when I execute my JAR with
java -jar .\QuartzScheduler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class com.quartz.QuartzSchedulerApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.quartz.QuartzSchedulerApplication

This is a snippet of my build.gradle, please help to shed some light on this.
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com.quartz'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.4.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.20.0'
    implementation files('C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 12.6 for SQL Server\\sqljdbc_12.6\\enu\\jars\\mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar')
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.withType(Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.quartz.QuartzSchedulerApplication"
    }
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveClassifier = ''

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class' : "com.quartz.QuartzSchedulerApplication"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

QuartzSchedulerApplication.class
package com.quartz;

import com.quartz.info.TriggerInfo;
import com.quartz.jobs.HelloWorldJob;
import com.quartz.services.SchedulerService;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QuartzSchedulerApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(QuartzSchedulerApplication.class);

    private final SchedulerService scheduler;

    @Autowired
    public QuartzSchedulerApplication(SchedulerService scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuartzSchedulerApplication.class, args).getBean(QuartzSchedulerApplication.class).scheduleJobs();
    }

    public void scheduleJobs() {
        final TriggerInfo info = new TriggerInfo();

        info.setCronExp("5 0/1 * * * ?"); // Run every min, at 5th second
        info.setCallbackData("HelloWorldJob");
        scheduler.schedule(HelloWorldJob.class, info);
        LOG.debug("test");
    }
}

I started off building my Quartz project with Log4j and it was successful. Also, I verified that the JAR file contains my main class and manifest file also exists. When I run the application using bootJar, it was also successful.
I also tried executing the JAR file using:
java -cp .\QuartzScheduler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.quartz.QuartzSchedulerApplication

I'm not sure if it is due to the implementation of JDBC.
Apologies, I did not add the requirement of Log4j2 in my question. Although I am able to execute my jar file by removing the jar task and jar task configuration, my Log4j2 logging does not work anymore. I know this because I isolated my application, same as above, just without JDBC and the logging works fine. Any advice?


Remove version from spring-boot-starter-jdbc you are now mixing versions of Spring BOot. 2. ditch the tasks.withType(Jar) and jar tasks, you are now basically fighting with the default Spring BOot plugin which already creates a fatjar for you.


thank you so much @M.Deinum! It works but actually the tasks were originally used for executing my jar in a separately folder, taking in properties file to run dynamically.

You can still run it dynamically no need to have another jar task for that. Copy that jar to the folder you need to or include the properties into the jar and use profiles to switch between different configuration.

I removed the [log4j2] tag, since the error has nothing to do with logging.

The problem is your build file. You are working around the work that the Gradle Spring Boot plugin is doing. Next to that you are mixing modules from different Spring Boot versions never do that either.
The solution is thus quite simple, simplify/cleanup your build.gradle.

Remove the version from the spring-boot-starter-jdbc
Remove the jar task and jar task configuration.
Remove the duplicate mssql-jdbc dependency (remove the file one)

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com.quartz'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.20.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Now just build your jar as you normally would with ./gradlew build and Spring Boot will automatically create a jar for you that you can run with java -jar QuartzScheduler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Does that mean file and runtime mssql-jdbc conflict with each other?
i have the following running in my main and it only works when i have this implementation files('C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 12.6 for SQL Server\\sqljdbc_12.6\\enu\\jars\\mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar')
`
User user1 = context.getBean(User.class);
user1.setId(1);
user1.setGender("Male");
        UserRepo repo = context.getBean(UserRepo.class);
        repo.save(user1);

`

It will pick the first one that comes on the classpath, but having 2 the same dependencies with different versions is generally a recipe for disaster. So don't do that. If you need the that specific version just add it to the runtimeOnly variant and you can change it to implementation instead of runtimeOnly if you need.

Apologies, I did not add this the requirement of Log4j2 in my question. Although I am able to execute my jar file, by removing the jar task and jar task configuration, my Log4j2 logging does not work anymore. I know this because I isolated my application, same as above, just without JDBC and the logging works fine. Any advise?

All Spring Boot starters bring a Logback-based stack as transitive dependency, which conflicts with your Log4j Core-based stack. To change this: 1. Remove the explicit version from log4j-api, 2. Exclude spring-boot-starter-logging from all configurations. 3. Remove log4j-core and log4j-slf4j-impl and replace them with a runtimeOnly spring-boot-starter-log4j2. See Installing Log4j Core for Spring Boot applications for more details.

Thanks for pointing out and helping a noobie! @PiotrP.Karwasz
